# Run Laravel local server behind proxy

Tags: laravel, proxy, localserver

I have a laravel project. This project sends and receives data to/from an api. this api checks my server ip address to ensure that it's me (it's bank's api). I set my real server's proxy to windows proxy settings, my server's ip is known by the api. the problem is when I run my laravel locally, it doesn't use my system proxy settings.
I just tested api and my proxy settings, there is no problem when I use postman.
I tried these:

1. set proxy and port in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Internet Options`.
2. set proxy and port in system settings (Windows 10 settings).
3. used commands in project folder: `set http_proxy=http://***.***.***.***:****/` and `set https_proxy=http://***.***.***.***:****/`.

my os: windows 10 and 
laravel version: 6

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the same issue. Can't see how to set http proxy in Laravel.

Comment: @Joe in my case I needed proxy to send cURL request to a bank api that checks request ip. My problem solved by adding proxy to my cURL options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set proxy settings for each part separately. For example if you use PHP cURL to send requests to api, you can do it like that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => 'PROXY:PORT', // or USER:PASS@PROXY:PORT if your proxy need authentication
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => $method,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $body,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $header,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

or if you use SoapClient:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('URL', [  // Replace "URL" with your api URL
    'proxy_host'     => 'HOST',  // Replace "HOST" with your proxy address
    'proxy_port'     => 'PORT',  // Replace "PORT" with your proxy port
    'proxy_login'    => 'USER',  // Replace "USER" with your proxy authentication username. 
                                 // (if your proxy server needs authentication,
                                 // otherwise delete this line and below line.)
    'proxy_password' => 'PASS',  //Replace "PASS" with your proxy authentication username.
]);
```